# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField does not show in Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am adding a `DropdownFormField` and `TextFormField` side by side inside a Row. This is what the build function looks like

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                DropdownButton(
                  hint: new Text('Select Gender'),
                  items: _salutations,
                  value: client.salutation,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      return value.isEmpty ? 'Empty name.' : '';
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

That code currently shows because it is DropdownButton. But if I change it to DropdownButtonFormField it won't show, as long as it is in the Row(). Why is this?

I wish to use DropdownButtonFormField so that the height of the Dropdown will be the same as the TextFormField since the current code shows the dropdown with a smaller height.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try out like this,

```
List<String> valueList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  String _value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: new DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      hint: new Text('Select'),
                      items: valueList.map((String value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  new Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                        validator: (value) {
                          return value.isEmpty ? 'Empty name.' : '';
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`DropdownButtonFormField` must have a width inside `Row` so wrap it inside a `Container` and set `width` for that `Container`

Hope this could help..

Comment: ill try this tomorrow but quick ques. why doesnt it work without a width? i would hope it will set the width based on the content. and the textformfield will then take up the remaining space.

Comment: If the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.

Comment: Thanks, this works with regards to width. i removed the height though, and used an InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.5)) so that the height of the drop down form field and the text field  form field are the same. The issue here though is that when the text field receives focus, the dropdown does not show the list anymore. weird.

Comment: Thanks dear ChyperX. Row -> Container "with width" -> DropdownButtonFormField worked like charm :)